# adding trimmed substrings

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, substr, charindex

using sql server:

I have a number of commands that trim a txt file, example:

```
Case when charindex('-', Substring([RawStreamOut], 179, 10)) > 0   
                then '-' + Replace(LTrim(RTRIM(Substring([RawStreamOut], 179, 9))), ',','')  else
                        LTrim(RTRIM(Substring([RawStreamOut], 179, 10))) end as [Days_Old_16_To_20],

Case when charindex('-', Substring([RawStreamOut], 196, 10)) > 0   
                then '-' + Replace(LTrim(RTRIM(Substring([RawStreamOut], 196, 9))), ',','')  else
                        LTrim(RTRIM(Substring([RawStreamOut], 196, 10))) end as [Days_Old_21_To_40]
```

etc...

I have a number of these.

current output:

[image: i need the total value column to do a calculation of all my days old columns]

I need to be able to add the results of these commands into a new column named "total". is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What RDBMS is this? SQL Server? Please [edit] your question and add the apropriate tag! And please add some sample data and some sample output or even better a [mre] along with sample data.

Comment: hi ocaso, thanks for that. i have updated it based off your comments

Comment: Share the sample data and output instead of image.

Comment: Probably the only reasonable way is to create a view or use the block of charindex in a CTE then just use that as part of your update, assuming your `days_old...` columns are static.

Comment: how do i share the sample data? i cannot attach it as a txt file, an example of a line of the data is = '''17885049     ZRD3 90781856-03        Access Subassy,Cut Formed,Anterior Curve 04/14/2015   1,496             0.00             0.00             0.00             0.00             0.00             0.00           192.12  12/10/2015  1 2021-03-29 11:41:02.250 13
60000 2021-03-29 11:41:02.250 14'''' i then use the trim function to put the data into columns

Comment: thanks @Stu. yes my columns are static. do you have an example on how i would do a view/CTE? im not that familiar with using this function

Comment: *"how do i share the sample data?"* As DDL and DML statements preferably; then we can can just copy and paste the SQL into our RDBMS and have the data. If not **well formatted** tabular `text`.

Comment: Though, what's wrong with `Days_Old_11_To_15 + Days_Old_16_To_20 +... AS Total_Value`?

Comment: @Larnu that wouldnt work in the same query though would it? would i need to create the columns in a query first, then have a separate query for that calculation?

Comment: You can't reference a column by its alias in the same `SELECT`, no, @d_chawke , but that's not a problem with a subquery/CTE. There are literally 1,000's (if not 10,000's or even 100,000's or more) examples showing you how to use a CTE/subquery out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you now have is:

```
select 
    case when charindex........as [Days_Old_16_To_20]
    ,.......
from
    (bunch of tables and joins)
```

Instead, put your formulas in a cross apply:

```
select
    q.*
from 
    (bunch of tables and joins)
    cross apply
    ( select
        case when charindex........as [Days_Old_16_To_20]
        ,.......
    ) as q
```

Now you can add a new column to your select which will be :

```
select
    q.[Days_Old_16_To_20] + q.[Days_Old_21_To_40] + .... as [Total_value]
    ,q.*
from 
    (bunch of tables and joins)
    cross apply
    ( select
        case when charindex........as [Days_Old_16_To_20]
        ,.......
    ) as q
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to use a `view`

Create view SomeView as

```
select...
Case when charindex('-', Substring([RawStreamOut], 179, 10)) ..... end as [Days_Old_16_To_20],
Case when charindex('-', Substring([RawStreamOut], 196, 10)) ..... end as [Days_Old_21_To_40]
.
.
from <tables>
```

Then your query can simply be

```
select 
    column, 
    [Days_Old_16_To_20] + [Days_Old_21_To_40] +... as total_Value
from someView
```

Comment: thanks Stu, this also works along with George, if i could accept both as an answer i would! :)